# Create WordPress post from self-hosted Gitlab Markdown page

Tags: wordpress, gitlab, markdown

We have a self-hosted, private Gitlab server where we are hosting some documentation in the form of markdown pages. This documentation is supposed to go on our website's (a WordPress server hosted on WP Engine) knowledge base.

I am trying to figure out if I can push the content from the markdown pages on Gitlab to our website in the form of a post. Trying to keep the documentation in sync between the two as developers and others within the organization will be updating the documentation in Gitlab and I would like it to sync back to WordPress.

I foresee a couple of potential issues:

1. The Gitlab server being self-hosted and private means that I can't just used a WordPress plugin to retrieve the information from the Gitlab server.
2. The WordPress server being hosted on WP Engine restricts what I can install on the web server's backend.

I have tried installing WP-CLI on a server where I have my local version of my Gitlab documentation repository, but I am unable to install git on the WordPress web server to establish a connection there to be able to push after pulling from Gitlab server.

Comment: What's your *actual* question? All you've really done here is describe your current situation, but it's not clear what *specifically* you need help with. See [ask]

Comment: Have you considered working in a component to your CI/CD pipeline that adds/updates the requisite pages via Wordpress' API when committing to your private repository? That, to me, sounds most logical in this scenario, but there are quite a few other ways this could be accomplished. How are you serving the markdown-formatted content in Wordpress?

Comment: Hey @esqew, sorry for not responding earlier! I will give it a try with a CI/CD pipeline. This just kind of got dumped in my lap so I am trying to put it all together as streamlined as possible!